# Would you please tell me what "than that of" means here?

Tags: vocabulary

> "Look into the motives which have induced men, once united by their
>   common needs in a general society, to unite themselves still more
>   intimately by means of civil societies: you will find no other motive
>   ***than that of*** assuring the property, life and liberty of each member by
>   the protection of all."

Would anyone please tell me what the following means?, or what does than that of assuring mean?

> ... ***than that of*** assuring the property, life and liberty of each member
>   by the protection of all."

And, Would you possibly elaborate this:assuring the property, life and liberty of each member by the protection of all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please give the source?

Your sentence is

> You will find no other motive **than that of** assuring the property, life and liberty of each member by the protection of all.

**"that"** here stands for **"motive"**.
So rewriting the sentence with he replacement of **"that"** we find

> You will find no other motive **than the motive of** assuring the property, life and liberty of each member by the protection of all.

Here are a few more example sentences which have similar kind of construction -

> 1. The language used was simpler and chattier **than that of** Pravda or even of Trud , the main labor organ.
> 2. In Zambia, although it has a population at least ten times smaller **than that of** Nigeria, localism has also been the prime concern of domestic politics.

Is it fine now?

Comment: http://gmatclub.com/forum/the-first-and-most-important-rule-of-legitimate-or-popular-g-110284.html

Comment: Great. Would you possibly elaborate this:assuring the property, life and liberty of each member by the protection of all.

Comment: Consider this part - "More motive than the motive of A". Does it make sense? If it does, now consider this - "No other motive than the motive of A". If this does I guess you can understand your sentence.

Comment: @nima_persian In this kind of construction, "that" implies something that is already mentioned and well understood. I will try to add some more examples in my answer.